# Given a solution to a differential equation, find the second order DE which satisfies the solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I am given the solution to a second order differential equation and I need to find a differential equation which satisfies the solution. I am unsure how to do this as the solution to the DE, $y(x)$, involves hypergeometric functions.
$$y(x)=\frac{-5613521}{561555}\operatorname{hypergeom} \left( \left[\frac{-107244524}{111546435}, \frac{14828657}{44618574}\right],\left[\frac{-82239602}{111546435}\right],x\right)-\frac{12127728}{37182145}x^{\frac{193786037}{111546435}} \operatorname{hypergeom} \left( \left[\frac{28847171}{37182145}, \frac{3879961}{1874730}\right],\left[\frac{305332472}{111546435}\right],x\right)$$

I need to find, (a) A second-order linear differential equation for which $y(x)$ is the solution and (b) A second-order linear homogeneous differential equation for which $y(x)$ is the solution.